# How can I get the name of the most expensive product with XPath 2.0

Tags: xpath

The table is:

```
<products>
<TITLE> PRODUCT TABLE DATA </TITLE>
<produc>
     <denomination> MSI G41M-P26 Motherboard </denomination>
     <price> 50 </price>
   </produc>
   <produc>
     <denomination> Micro Intel Core i5-2320 </denomination>
     <price> 120 </price>
   </produc>
</products>
```

If I put 
`max(/products//price)`
it returns 120, but I don't know how to get the Denomination of the product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XPath for getting the denomination node:

```
/products//produc[price=max(/products//price)]/denomination
```

XPath for getting the denomination text:

```
/products//produc[price=max(/products//price)]/denomination/text()
```

I tested it [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html) successfully.